# Como abrir uma Dialog no android

Tags: android, dialog

Queria saber como faço para abrir uma dialog para o usuário poder inserir texto, logo que ele clicar no botão, a caixa para digitar é aberta e logo que ele digitar irá ter um botão de salvar e cancelar, como poderei fazer isso ?

```
private ImageView imgsavesom;

imgsavesom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgsavesom);
imgsavesom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Criar um objecto File com o caminho actual
            Intent intent = new Intent("grav_som"); //grav_som eh o nome do  layout

            startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

eu não sei como ir para o layout através do `Intent`, sou leigo em android

O meu `onActivityResult()` já está sendo usado para outra coisa, tem problema sobre o startActivity(intent); ?

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resCode, data);
    if(resCode == RESULT_OK)    {
        if (reqCode == 1)
            contactImgView.setImageURI(data.getData());
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        imagePath = getImagePath(imageUri);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, imagePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Você não precisa apenas abrir o dialog? 
esse "grav_som" é o layout que possui a dialog? 
sua preocupação e quando clicar em "cancelar"?

Comment: eu quero somente abrir o dialog, o grav_som seria o layout que você me passou, e minha preocupação é quando clica no botão, ele abre o dialog onde está o layout que você me passou na sua resposta

Comment: Já testou? o dialog abriu?

Comment: ele não abre, ele fecha o programa

Comment: Posta o erro do Log Cat, para analise! @Gabriel Santana Bonatto

Comment: desculpa a demora, mas não estou conseguindo pegar as informações certa do logcat do android studio, ele é diferente do eclipse que eu estava utilizando, poderia ajudar sobre isso?

Comment: Eu nunca usei o Android Studio. O log Cat, não mostra os erros lançados?

Comment: mostra, mas aparece um monte de coisa estranha, se quiser eu pego tudo isso e coloco aqui, quer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procurei bastante e achei

```js
ExibeDialog();

private void ExibeDialog(){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        
        //layout para o dialog
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_som);

        //define o título do Dialog
        dialog.setTitle("Nomear");

        //instancia os objetos que estão no layout customdialog.xml
        final Button confirmar = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnConfirmar);
        final Button cancelar = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelar);
        fianl EditText nome = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtnome);


        confirmar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
 

                //finaliza o dialog
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        cancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //finaliza o dialog
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        //exibe na tela o dialog
        dialog.show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para abrir uma caixa de dialog você pode utilizar o método `setOnClickListener` no id do seu botão ex: `btFinalizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()`

Ficaria algo parecido com isso :

```
//seu button 
private Button                      Abredialog;


//fica dentro do seu @OnCreate esse bloco

Abredialog= (Button) findViewById(R.id."seu id do botao que vem do layout");
//aqui você atribui ao seu botão o metodo setOnClickListener
Abredialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            //Aqui dentro do OnClick, você faz da mesma forma que você trabalha para abrir uma Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent("sua activity a ser aberta");
        startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Sua dialog pode ser criada da seguinte maneira em outro arquivo de `layout`:

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtOservacaoPedRota"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edtRota"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btCancelarObservaca"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert"
        android:text="@string/lblCancelar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btGravarObservacao"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
        android:text="@string/lblGravar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Na `Activity` do seu dialog você pode trabalhar da maneira que desejar, retornando para sua `Activity` ou prosseguindo o fluxo do app.

Comment: Eu coloquei a parti do OnClick que você colocou logo acima, poderia comentar cada linha da parte do OnClick para vê se eu entendo? porque o programa aqui esta fechando quando eu clico no botão :(
Eu gostaria de saber também que o meu onActivityResult já esta sendo usado para outra finalidade, se eu enviar como no caso dessa parte do código startActivity(intent) não irá dar problema sendo que ele está recebendo outros parâmetros porque está sendo usado para outro fim?

Comment: Eu fiz uma edição, veja se atende. 
@GabrielSantanaBonatto

Comment: editei a minha pergunta